# How to send data from styled component to a function?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I am trying to make a scrolling animation something like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/10886616-Rino-Pelle-Instagram://) using styled components and react. My strategy is to reduce the value of transform: scale(1) so that as the user scrolls down the image width and height will be reduced and similar effect will be obtained. To do that I need to access that property and use it in a function and then use it in an useEffect hook. I checked the documentation of styled components yet I guess I am missing something. Here is the code:

```
const AnimationImg = styled.img.attrs((props) => ({ src: props.src }))`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-origin: 49% 50%;
`;
const Animation = () => {
  //Scroll positionu yakalamami sagliyor.
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.pageYOffset;
    setScrollPosition(position);
  };

  const handleZoom = () => {
    if (scrollPosition >= 2000 && handleScroll) {
      // function here
    }
  };
```

zoom logic:

```
const handleZoom = () => {
    if (scrollPosition >= 2000 && handleScroll) {
      setZoom(zoom - 0.001);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `zoom` is derived from the `scrollPosition` state, you can recompute it whenever the component renders, and pass it as a prop to the styled component. Use interpolation inside scale to use the `zoom`.

```
const AnimationImg = styled.img`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  transform: scale(${({ zoom }) => zoom});
  transform-origin: 49% 50%;
`;

const Animation = () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  
  const zoom = scrollPosition >= 2000 ? zoomFunction(scrollPosition) : 1;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setScrollPosition(window.pageYOffset);
    };
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <AnimationImg zoom={zoom} />
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help! I was able to solve the problem by after extracting zoom and setting it a new value with setZoom using in useEffect hook.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need a separate state for the zoom value. Can you add the zoom logic to your question?

Comment: surely I added.

Comment: Your logic would require a state, since you use the previous state. However, the logic itself is faulty. If the user scrolls down and then up, the image would continue shrinking. I would create a logic based on the `scrollPosition` and then you can change the zoom on each render according to that logic, and you don't need a separate state.

Comment: okay thanks. I will implement in that way.